# updating date for a corresponding row value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying create the newdate column in the below dataset for a given start date(4/20 in the case below) for the respective invoice number with  requestdate less that the starting date(4/20). i tried setting up a counter with count of Invoice number but it didnt work.

Can someone help me here?

```
invoice#    RequestDate Newdate
123          4/18/2017  4/20/2017
123          4/16/2017  4/21/2017
123          4/17/2017  4/22/2017
126          4/15/2017  4/20/2017
126          4/16/2017  4/21/2017
126          4/17/2017  4/22/2017
126          4/18/2017  4/23/2017
126          4/19/2017  4/24/2017
131          4/13/2017  4/20/2017
131          4/14/2017  4/21/2017
131          4/15/2017  4/22/2017
131          4/16/2017  4/23/2017
131          4/17/2017  4/24/2017
131          4/18/2017  4/25/2017
131          4/19/2017  4/26/2017
```

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, can you post how you expect the data to be displayed?

Comment: @VDK i expect the date to be displayed in the above format which reflects the corresponding newdate(beginning 4/20 for each new invoice) for the requestdate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's determine the invoices you want to modify. We do this in the subquery PastInvoices. Then, you can use ROW_NUMBER() and [PARTITION BY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql) to create incrementing dates.

```
SELECT AllInvoices.invoice,
    RequestDate,
    CASE
        WHEN PastInvoices.invoice IS NOT NULL
        THEN DATEADD(day, (ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by AllInvoices.invoice order by AllInvoices.invoice)) - 1, GETDATE())
        ELSE RequestDate
    END as NewDate
FROM RequestDate as AllInvoices
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (select distinct invoice from RequestDate where RequestDate < GETDATE()) as PastInvoices
on AllInvoices.invoice = PastInvoices.invoice
```

Comment: GuillaumeGR did not see your solution. You hard coded 4-19 when the requestor asked for current date.

Comment: Lets see if Goal7 bothers marking your answer as correct.

Comment: @GuillaumeCR your previous answer was what i was looking for in case i want to change the date to something else than today's date.  For the example you asked previously(This means that if for example an invoice has 3 request dates of 4/19, 4/20 and 4/21, it will have newdates of 4/20, 4/20 and 4/21) what if i want to update it with 4/19,4/20, 4/22 for order 123? what changes should i make?

Comment: @Goal7 Did you mean 4/20, 4/21 and 4/22?

Comment: @GuillaumeCR Yes. apologies.

Comment: @Goal7 That becomes rather complex. I recommend just taking out the CASE and simply starting all NewDates from a common starting point. The complexity will come in this situation: What if an invoice has the following RequestDate: 4/15, 4/20 and 4/25. Do you expect 4/21, 4/20 and 4/25? If so, the query will become very complex, and hard to maintain.

Comment: @GuillaumeCR the dates for an invoice are never in a gap. they are always followed by the next date and don't skip days for the same invoice.  does it still become too complex?

Comment: @Goal7 answer updated, I think this meets all your requirements.

Comment: @GuillaumeCR you are the best Sir! thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

```
select invoice#,requestdate,
 row_number() over (partition by invoice# order by invoice#) + getdate() -1  as newdate
from t
```

Comment: The NEWDATE column in the data doesnt exists. Its something i want to create using the request date and invoice#. Does it make sense?

Comment: @Goal7 no that doesn't make sense. Please explain how you intend on creating the NewDate column and how you will populate it.

Comment: @GuillaumeCR I need help creating the the NewDate column. Basically if on a given date(4/20 in this case) i want to find all the request dates that are already past due and update them starting with the current date until the invoice# ends. hence you see invoice# 123 in the above example has a new date starting with 4/20 for a request date of 4/18, followed by 4/19 with a new date of 4/21

Comment: You listed a bunch of rows with a newdate column. I regret answering your question because its ill formed and I am going to get dinged. The logic is not clear. You want requestdate for all invoice 123 to be replaced with what date?

Comment: @Goal7 In your example, the NewDate for invoice 123 goes from 4/20 to 4/22 while the requestdate goes from 4/18 to 4/16. For invoice 126, all your newdates are exactly 5 days after your requestdate. These look like opposite patterns. Which one is it?

Comment: @GuillaumeCR its both. It changes based on the times the PO number is published. Hence 123 needs updated 3 times and 126 5 times

Comment: @Goal7 So, just to be clear: You want NewDate to start at 4/20, and to increment by 1 for every row within a invoice, and only for rows with requestdate < 4/20. What if an invoice has some request date < 4/20 and some > 4/20?

Comment: @GuillaumeCR yes on your question of increment by 1 for the corresponding invoice starting at 4/20. For the dates that are >4/20 i want them to be left alone meaning they can have the same value as before.

Comment: @Goal7 This means that if for example an invoice has 3 request dates of 4/19, 4/20 and 4/21, it will have newdates of 4/20, 4/20 and 4/21.

Comment: @GuillaumeCR ideally would like 4/20,4/21 but the above works too.

Comment: I thnik I understand your logic now. Look at my solution please. Thanks to GuilaumeCR for very patiently eliciting details.